# How to inspect element without using xpath

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, capybara

I still have difficulty in some situations of not avoiding xpath. For this problem below how to avoid it ?. Someone has a website that teaches many ways to do this .. Thank you very much.

this class is repeated more than once on the page.

'//*[@id="gatsby-focus-wrapper"]/div/div/div/main/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kzy8E.png)/span[2]'

See the picture please.

[image]

Comment: Please don't include images like this; they aren't testable. There are certainly other ways to find information other than XPath, but since no one else knows what your tests are or how they're failing, you're unlikely to get help unless you update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't state what you're trying to do with that element, but there's most likely no need to check the full page structure since the element has text in it. Also using XPaths with the full page structure are going to make your tests very brittle.

If you want to find the element you could do

```
find('span', text: 'E-mail inválido')
```

or if you wanted to verify that it was within the `gatsby-focus-wrapper` you could do

```
find('#gatsby-focus-wrapper span', text: 'E-mail inválido')
```

If you were trying to verify it exists you could do

```
expect(page).to have_css('span', text: 'E-mail inválido') # using RSpec
```

or

```
asset_css('span', text: 'E-mail inválido') # using Minitest
```

If you needed/wanted to test for the class base too you could use a regex with the class filter like

```
expect(page).to have_css(
  'span', 
  text: 'E-mail inválido', 
  class: /signUpFormFields__InputError\-/
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much !! ... If I map this element using a prism site, how would it be?.                      element :txt_email_blank,  ?????

Comment: or: element :txt_email_blank,            '#gatsby-focus-wrapper span', text: 'E-mail inválido'

Comment: @RebekaMontana Yes - site prisms `element` method takes the element name followed by any parameters you could pass to Capybaras `find` method

Comment: @RebekaMontana If this answered your question please don't forget to accept the answer so the question gets marked as answered